# Minimum required iOS SDK to publish to app store?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, app-store

What is the current minimum required iOS SDK I must target in order to successfully publish an app to the app store and where can I find this information in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple publishes updates to their requirements for iOS app submissions here: https://developer.apple.com/news/

Here is one of the news items where Apple updated their submission requirements: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05072018a

But check this site for any newer updates on the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can submit app for iOS 6.0 to  Latest iOS 9+.